# Calculating via months showing all for Jan?!? (MySql Workbench 6.3 CE)

Tags: mysql

I have a script which calculates the percentage increase or decrease against the previous months total. E.g. Jan's percentage will be 0, then whatever Feb's total is, the pecentage is worked out against Jan's etc.

I have created the table in sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2eac/2/0)

The results show every month as January, i want to see Jan, Feb, March etc, in the correct order, so that the percentage calculations are worked out correctly also. Any ideas?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2eac/2/0

```
SELECT monthname(concat('1970-', lpad('1', A.MONTH, '0'), '-01')) AS MONTH,
       A.SALES_AMOUNT,
       CASE
         WHEN A.SALES_AMOUNT IS NULL
           THEN NULL
         WHEN B.SALES_AMOUNT IS NULL
           THEN NULL
         WHEN A.SALES_AMOUNT = 0
           THEN NULL
         ELSE
           ROUND((B.SALES_AMOUNT / A.SALES_AMOUNT - 1) * 100,2)
       END AS PERCENTAGE
       FROM (SELECT month(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS MONTH,
                    ROUND(sum(SALES_AMOUNT),2) AS SALES_AMOUNT
                    FROM SALES
                    WHERE year(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
                    GROUP BY MONTH) A
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS MONTH,
                              ROUND(sum(SALES_AMOUNT),2) AS SALES_AMOUNT
                              FROM SALES
                              WHERE year(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
                              GROUP BY MONTH) B
                      ON A.MONTH - 1 = B.MONTH
       ORDER BY A.MONTH;
```

Result:

```
January 45163.22    
January 34531.15    30.79
January 44194.98    -21.87
January 30826.68    43.37
January 39016.04    -20.99
January 37284.25    4.64
January 37640.08    -0.95
January 39703.85    -5.20
January 34958.94    13.57
January 34447.61    1.48
January 39161.90    -12.04
January 36986.16    5.88
```

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: `2` is the second parameter to `round()` telling it to round the value to two decimal places.

Comment: indeed @stickybit coffee time.. totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks suspiciously like the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970673/calculate-percentage-on-previous-month-same-year/49971967#49971967). I made a mistake there, I thought I'd already edited out --  it's a leftover from a quick test. Turns out, I didn't, sorry for that.

Replace `monthname(concat('1970-', lpad('1', A.MONTH, '0'), '-01'))` with `monthname(concat('1970-', lpad(A.MONTH, 2, '0'), '-01'))`.

(And maybe consider accepting my answers if you use them.)

---

Edit:

Switch roles of `A` and `B`:

```
SELECT monthname(concat('1970-', lpad(A.MONTH, 2, '0'), '-01')) AS MONTH,
       A.SALES_AMOUNT,
       CASE
         WHEN A.SALES_AMOUNT IS NULL
           THEN NULL
         WHEN B.SALES_AMOUNT IS NULL
           THEN NULL
         WHEN B.SALES_AMOUNT = 0
           THEN NULL
         ELSE
           ROUND((A.SALES_AMOUNT / B.SALES_AMOUNT - 1) * 100,2)
       END AS PERCENTAGE
       FROM (SELECT month(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS MONTH,
                    ROUND(sum(SALES_AMOUNT),2) AS SALES_AMOUNT
                    FROM SALES
                    WHERE year(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
                    GROUP BY MONTH) A
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS MONTH,
                              ROUND(sum(SALES_AMOUNT),2) AS SALES_AMOUNT
                              FROM SALES
                              WHERE year(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
                              GROUP BY MONTH) B
                      ON A.MONTH - 1 = B.MONTH
       ORDER BY A.MONTH;
```

Comment: Calculations do not work out correctly. If month 1 total is 45163.22, Month 2 is 34531.15, this should show a decrease of -23.54%, yet the calculation and percentage shows an increase of 30.79%?